# C 2D Array rotating

Tags: c

I have a 2D pointer setup representing a grid, the grid consists of columns containing 1/0 or null columns (i.e. don't contain 1 in any cell). This function spins the grid by 90deg clockwise, and works except...

I think my malloc could be wrong as it works but I get many over picket-fence errors in dmalloc.

Am I allocating incorrect amounts of memory?

Also I wanted to swap the values of *width and *height to represent the new width and height of the grid but when I try this the program just segfaults on the second spin.

Comment: Of curiosity, is there a reason you don't malloc the whole grid at once, but rather malloc it line by line?

Comment: But it can free() all the memory, can't it? By the end of the function, there might be nothing left, so it can segfault (on the second spin).

Comment: By inserting diagnostic printfs at strategic points in your code, can you pinpoint where the fault occurs?

Comment: @thb - if the whole array was malloc'd in one, it would have to be accessed using 'by hand' 2D access, i.e. instead of `newg[x][y]` it would be something like `newg[*height * x + y]`

Comment: @gbulmer yes, this is why it isn't malloced at once.

Comment: Fair enough.  Don't change your design now, since you're committed to it for the moment.  However, if you decide to rewrite it later from scratch, consider doing it by hand, exactly as @gbulmer suggests.  If so, then I suspect that you might be happier using the one, contiguous block of memory.

Comment: Is there a strong reason why orig has 'null` columns/rows? It seems to create an extra class of bug. Does *width correspond to orig's first index, orig[i], or its second index orig[][i]? It looks like they may have been swapped, but frankly using width+heigh as well as x and y is _not_ super-clear to me. I'd use max_x and max_y to try to make the relationships clearer. Put another way, I think newg[x] might need to be *height, and newg[][y] might need to be *width

Comment: @gbulmer *width corresponds to orig[i]. My main problem is the memory leak, is it possible I am allocating too little memory here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So *width is the dimension of orig's first dimension, so it should be the size of newg's second dimension.

Similarly *height should be the size of newg's first, and hence the two sets of malloc sizes have been flipped the wrong way around.

I think it would be clearer to name the values orig_max_x and orig_max_y, then it should be clear if the function uses the values the wrong way around.

```
    newg = malloc (*height * sizeof(char *));

    // Initialise each column
    for (x = 0; x < *height; x++) {
        newg[x] = malloc (*width);
        for (y = 0; y < *width; y++)
            newg[x][y] = 0;
    }
```

Further, it should **not free any** of newg's storage if you want to return values from `spin()`

Edit: I still had some of those pesky *width and *height mixed. Sorry.
I strongly suggest the names should relate to the thing they talk about, orig_width, 
orig_height would be have helped me read the code.

This is probably how I'd do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char** alloc_rectangle(int *width, int *height);
void free_rectangle(char **orig, int *width);
char** spin (char **orig, int *width, int *height);

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int width = 20;
    int height = 30;

    char** orig = alloc_rectangle(&width, &height);
    char** newg = spin(orig, &width, &height);


    return 0;
}

char** alloc_rectangle(int *width, int *height) 
{
    char **newg = calloc (*width, sizeof(char *));

    // Initialise each column
    for (int x = 0; x < *width; x++) {
        newg[x] = calloc (*height, sizeof(char));
    }
    return newg;
}

void free_rectangle(char **orig, int *width)
{
    // free memory for old grid
    for (int x = 0; x < *width; x++) {
        if (orig[x] != NULL) {
            free (orig[x]);
        }
    }

    free (orig);
}

char** spin (char **orig, int *width, int *height) 
{
    int x;
    int y;

    char **newg = alloc_rectangle(height, width);

    // Rotate
    for (x = 0; x < *width; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < *height; y++)
            if (orig[x] != NULL) 
                newg[*height - 1 - y][x] = orig[x][y];
    }

    return newg;
}
```

**WARNING** Untested code - some fun for all :-)

I don't think it is spin's job to free orig. I'd prefer it to just make space to hold the result of spinning. So to make things tidier, I pulled freeing a rectangle into its own function. Similarly, I'd always want the rectangles to be allocated consistently, so that would be its own function.

Comment: I understand this but even when using *height instead of *width in the initial malloc I get many memory leaks.

Comment: Sorry - I did an incomplete job - please have another look at my code.

Answer (score 1):

Take another look at the code that rotates the grid.  I don't think you ever want to mix `x` and `y` coordinates, so an index like `*width - 1 - y` looks suspicious.  For example, suppose `*width = 3` and `*height = 5`.  Then `y` ranges from 0 to 4, and you can end up with `newg[3 - 1 - 4]` = `newg[-2]`.

Also, if you've allocated `orig` the same way you allocated `newg` you'll need to free it like this:

```
for (x=0; x < *width; x++) {
  free (orig[x]);  // Free the individual columns
}
free (orig); // Free the array of pointers.
```

Comment: @user1277546:  Well, consider:  The maximum value of `y` in that loop is `*height - 1`.  When `y` has that value, what is the value of `*width - 1 - y`?  Isn't it `*height - *width`, which could be a negative number?

Comment: @Adam Liss The orig grid will have columns set to null, so I think the current way works the same?

Comment: @thb Hmmm... is there a better way to spin a 2d array by 90deg cw?

Comment: @user1277546:  Well, there is often a better way to do something, and I probably would not have done it your way, but that is not important.  What we want now is to get your way to work, and one suspects that this can be done.  However, I *think* that Adam is right.  I think that your code sometimes gives a negative number as the first index to `newg[][]`.

Comment: (@user1277546:  Since you ask the question directly, yes, I personally feel that there is a better way.  Malloc a single, `width*height`-sized block of memory for the 2D array, and perform indexing by hand -- or write some suitable helper functions or preprocessor macros to do the indexing for you.  Contiguous blocks of memory are usually preferable in applications like this, if my experience is a guide.  I emphasize however that I am not trying to talk you into abandoning your approach!  It just does not happen to be the approach I probably would have used.)

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote this up quickly and it seemed to work fine with the few tests I ran on it.

```
char **rotate(char **original, int *width, int *height)
{
    int t_width = *height;
    int t_height = *width;

    char **newgrid = (char**)calloc(t_height, sizeof(char*));

    for(int y = 0; y < t_height; y++)
    {
        newgrid[y] = (char*)calloc(t_width, sizeof(char));
        for(int x = 0; x < t_width; x++)
            newgrid[y][x] = original[x][y];         
    }

    for(int y = 0; y < *height; y++)
        free(original[y]);
    free(original);

    *width = t_width;
    *height = t_height;

    return newgrid;
}
```

Let me know if there are any problems.